# Clicking OptionButton after selecting Group Box gives error

Tags: excel, vba, validation, groupbox, radio-button

I have a sheet with named ranges, a user cell [OB_DropDown], and a couple of option buttons in a group box.  The yellow cell changes its drop down menu depending on the option button selected.

[image]

I've assigned macros to each of the Option Buttons:

```
Sub OB_Colors()

    [OB_DropDown].Validation.Delete
    [OB_DropDown].Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:="=Drop_Colors"

End Sub

Sub OB_Sizes()

    [OB_DropDown].Validation.Delete
    [OB_DropDown].Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:="=Drop_Sizes"

End Sub
```

Everything works fine, but when I click the Group Box (the frame is selected) and then click one of the Option Buttons, I get a '1004' run-time error.  The code points to the .Validation.Add line.  Anyone know why?

Comment: Show detail error message. `Run-time error '1004'` have another detail error message. If you say, we can think more.

Comment: The message is "Application-defined or object-defined error".

Answer (score 0):

OK, Try with this.

```
Sub OB_Colors()

    Sheets("sheetname").Range("OB_DropDown").Validation.Delete
    Sheets("sheetname").Range("OB_DropDown").Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:="=Drop_Colors"

End Sub

Sub OB_Sizes()

    Sheets("sheetname").Range("OB_DropDown").Validation.Delete
    Sheets("sheetname").Range("OB_DropDown").Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:="=Drop_Sizes"

End Sub
```

Comment: No, my sheet is not protected.  I tried doing Unprotect/Protect and the problem still occurs.  I don't understand how selecting the Group Box affects adding a validation list.

Comment: OK, I modified my code. Try it. If it is not working, tell me.